# Why bash regex with =~ doesn't work in place

Tags: regex, bash

Following code doesn't work

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

line=" 12345 file /my/path"
[[ $line =~ ^\s*(\S*)\s+(\S*)\s+(\S*) ]]
var1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
var2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
var3=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

echo $var1
echo $var2
echo $var3
```

I expect output to be

```
12345
file
/my/path
```

But I got empty output

However, if i change the code as following, it worked as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

line=" 12345 file /my/path"
re='^\s*(\S*)\s+(\S*)\s+(\S*)'
[[ $line =~ $re ]]
var1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
var2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
var3=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

echo $var1
echo $var2
echo $var3
```

I try to understand it by reading the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)
.  But I still don't understand why for this case.  Can someone help explaining it to me?

Comment: Looks like part of expansion, where variables are converted into values, globs into file paths, etc.

Comment: consider `[[ 'x\Sx' =~ x\\\Sx ]]; declare -p BASH_REMATCH`

Comment: It is because you don't have a letter `s` or `S` in your string.

Comment: The way bash parses backslashes *before* evaluating the regular expression can conflict with their use in the regular expression itself. It's complicated and I don't fully understand it (and it's even inconsistent between different versions of bash).

Comment: According to [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs), "It is sometimes difficult to specify a regular expression properly without using quotes, or to keep track of the quoting used by regular expressions while paying attention to shell quoting and the shell’s quote removal. Storing the regular expression in a shell variable is often a useful way to avoid problems with quoting characters that are special to the shell."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s` and `\S` are not part of the ERE standard.

For maximum compatibility your regex should be written as:

```bash
[[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]*) ]]
```

That said, splitting on white-space and discarding the leading/trailing spaces can be easily done in `bash` with:

```bash
read -r var1 var2 var3 <<<"$line"
```

Comment: What exactly works depends on how exactly Bash was compiled. Some instances do support `\s` and `\S` because they were compiled against a version of the regex library which supports this feature. But obviously, depending on that is bad practice.

Comment: ("the regex library" being part of libc, to be clear)